# Display PDF in offline WebApp / Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, pdf, web-applications

I'm looking for a solution to display an embedded PDF Document in a WebApp that runs offline on an iPad. I tried some JS / jQuery Scripts but none of them support the common multitouch gestures (pinch to zoom / swype to switch page). They do only show the PDF without any further functionality.

PDF.JS isn't a solution as well, because it runs only on firefox browsers.

Can you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Run PDF.js in the SVG mode? Just to notice, PDF.js is designed to run on any browser that supports HTML5. Apperently Safari is not a such thing (Chrome for iPad is just a Safari in different dress)

Answer (score 1):

this can be done with the UIWebView.

If you are trying to display a PDF file residing on a server somewhere, you can simple load it to your web view directly:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/UIWebView_Class.pdf"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Or if you have a PDF file bundled with your application (in this example named "document.pdf"):

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 200)];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"document" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];

[self.view addSubview:webView];
```